# How to combine two map into a json data

Tags: java, json, api

I have a map which is like below

```
Map<String,List<status>> statusmap=new HashMap<String,List<status>>();
```

So when I output this map as a JSON data then I do the following:

```
return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,List<status>>>(statusmap,HttpStatus.OK);
```

which gives the below JSON data.

```
{"status":[{"connection":"OK","message":"Success"}]}
```

As above I also have another map

```
Map <String,List<Model>> modelmap= new HashMap<String,List<Model>>();
```

So when I output this map as a JSON data then I do the following:

```
return new ResponseEntity<Map <String,List<Model>>>
```

which gives the below JSON data.

```
 {"apidata":[{"id":1,"score":8},{"id":2,"score":6},{"id":3,"score":5}]}.
```

Now I want the both data to be combined in the sense

```
{"status":[{"connection":"OK","message":"Success"}],"apidata":[{"id":1,"score":8},{"id":2,"score":6},{"id":3,"score":5}]}
```

I tried with `Map<Map<String,List<status>>,Map <String,List<Model>>> result=new HashMap <Map<String,List<status>>,Map <String,List<Model>>>();
result.put(statusmap,modelmap);`

But It did not come as the wanted format.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two maps:

```
Map<String,List<status>> statusmap=new HashMap<String,List<status>>();
Map<String,List<Model>> modelmap= new HashMap<String,List<Model>>();
```

Combine them as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> combinedMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

combinedMap.putAll(statusmap);
combinedMap.putAll(modelmap);
```

You may need to do some extra casting (untested code).  Then just use a ResponseEntity like:

```
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>();
```

Comment: Work like a charm